# Optimal circles placement - geospatial

Tags: python, geospatial

I am trying to solve the following problem:

1. I have 1000 points (lat,lon) scattered on a map
2. Each point has a value call it x_i
3. I need to put n circles with radii r_i < 5 miles such that the sum of the points' values x_i in the circle is s_i > 200
4. Circles can't intersect

I have to maximize the sum of all s_i. The variables are: all r_i, n, positions of circles (which points I pick as centers of my circles).

Can someone help me with some guidance on how to solve something like this?

**UPDATE**
I am fixing all r_i and we can assume that they have known values from the start.

Comment: There are PhD-level courses about solving problems like this one. Can you narrow it down, so the answer could fit into a single SO response?

Comment: @Marat. This is as narrow as I can get it. Could you please suggest any paper I could potentially have a look at?

Comment: This is more of a field than a single paper. You are looking for dynamic optimization or non-convex optimization methods. Without exploiting some properties of your dataset, solving it to optimality (find the true max sum) will be really hard.

Comment: I would probably starting from greedy algorithms and branch and bound. Greedy approach doesn't guarantee optimality, but it might be good enough. Branch and bound does guarantee optimality but its performance highly depends on what heuristics you can use to produce the bounds.

Comment: What if I randomly select say 30 points and randomly select radii that match the 200 condition multiple times hoping for a greedy solution. If no solution after 100k iterations, I go to 20, then 25 etc. Based on my analysis on the data, you shouldn’t be able to draw more than 30 circles.

Comment: Look for Openshaw's optimal bombing strategy paper, late 1980s I think

Comment: Managed to simplify the problem. What if all radii are known and have fixed values for every point?

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/20001931?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents and https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0260982782900143 may help