# Performance improvement - search over dict (id -> list of lists)

Tags: python, performance, python-itertools

I have a list of all combinations of some ids `combinations(ids,10))` and a dictionary id `->` list of lists `id_to_pos`. `distances cache` is just tuple `->` float

I am trying to do the following:

- for every combination of 10 ids

  - for every combination of 2 lists from the dictionary
  - compare some floats between them

The code I wrote is the following:

```
from itertools import combinations
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import product
from tqdm import tqdm

for ids in tqdm((combinations(id_to_pos, 10))):
    rows = itemgetter(*ids)(id_to_pos)
    rows_opt = [v for v in product(*rows)]
    for row in rows_opt:
        broken = False
        row_combs = list(combinations(row, 2))
        for sample1,sample2 in row_combs:
            if distances_cache[(sample1[0],sample2[0])]<(sample1[3]+sample2[3]):
                broken = True
                break
        if broken:
            continue
```

I am wondering how I can make this faster. Maybe use numpy (might run out of memory)? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: What's the real goal, what's the big picture? There might be an appropriate algorithm from graph theory or involving k-d-trees, but it's hard to tell now.

Comment: I am trying to solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57929138/optimal-circles-placement-geospatial?noredirect=1#comment102276619_57929138

Comment: Basically I have all the "circles" that match the conditions except the fact that I don't know whether they overlap. I do a search across all possible combination of 10 circles and get the first combination that matches the criteria